# Running a thread automatically when items added to a list object in java

Tags: java, multithreading, linked-list

I am implementing a task, where I have a class say `Email` which contains a LinkedList which contains all the emails that are to be sent. I have several classes which add an email to this queue.

Now, what I want is that, class `Email` automatically starts a thread whenever an element is added in LinkedList object until all the emails have been sent. Could I have some guidance over this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you write an EmailSender class which uses an ExecutorService instead of a queue to submit a task to send the email.

Passing a collection around which has side effects is a bad idea. e.g. what happens if the caller calls

- addAll() - add multiple emails?
- remove() - cancel an email already added the queue?
- retainAll() - cancel all but the emails listed?
- clear() - cancel all emails?

you are exposing all sorts of functionality which might not be implemented or make sense.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on `ExecutorService` in this context or provide me some example. I have never used that before

Comment: The ExecutorService was added to Java 5.0 in 2004 to provide a wrapper for a queue and a thread pool.  You can submit tasks to a pool of threads which you can control collectively or individually. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html

Comment: Thanks man, for introducing me to a new feature. I have implemented it by `ExecutorService` instead of queue. It is much cleaner and easy to manage

Answer (score 2):

Replace `LinkedList<Email>` with [`LinkedBlockingDequeue<Email>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html), start your thread immediately, and pass it the queue. The thread should call `queue.take()`, which will block until an e-mail becomes available. Essentially, you'll get a dormant thread waiting on the receiving end of the queue, producing the effect that you want: any time an e-mail is inserted into the queue, the reading thread would wake up, grab the new e-mail, process it, and go back to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Use a BlockingQueue for the list.  Hang threads off it.  The threads loop around the queue take() call and, when the get an Email instance, send it and then return to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having each of the several classes you have mentioned adding elements to `Email`'s `LinkedList` directly, you should implement a method (e.g. `public void addEmail(...)`) in the `Email` class and have tose other classes call that method and pass the new email as an argument.
In this `addEmail` method you could add the new email to the `LinkedList` (possibly after checking that it is not already in the list) and start the thread that you want to get automatically started.